# Add ViewPager to Activity which extends superclass with a Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have several activities which extend my class `DrawerActivity`, so they will have a navigation drawer. Only one of these activities requires a `ViewPager`.

Question: How can I add a `ViewPager` to only one of the activities, `ActivityA`?

I am somewhat familiar with creating a `ViewPager`, but in this situation I'm unsure of where to put the `ViewPager` code, and what layouts to use. I've seen a few examples including the official tutorial on Google's developer site, but I'm not sure how to best implement it into my application.

I've provided some relevant code below, but please let me know if you need to see more. Any advice is appreciated, thanks!

In `DrawerActivity`'s `onCreate`:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment);

if (fragment == null)
{
    fragment = createFragment();
    fm.beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment)
            .commit();
}
```

Layout `activity_fragment.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView android:id="@+id/leftDrawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

In `ActivityA`:

```
public class ActivityA extends DrawerActivity
{
    //this is all I do in this activity
    @Override
    protected Fragment createFragment()
    {
        UUID id = (UUID) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(FragmentA.EXTRA_ID);
        return FragmentA.newInstance(id);
    }
}
```

In `FragmentA`'s `onCreateView`:

`View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, parent, false);`

Layout `fragment_a.xml` is a simple `LinearLayout` with a few `Button` and `TableLayout` children.

Answer (score 1):

fragment_a.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

         />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and create an adapter for example `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` and fill it with what you want to show in viewpager. notice that because you are using viewpager inside a fragment you should pass `ChildFragmentManaget` instead of activity `FragmentManager.`

Comment: Can I add the `ViewPager` portion of your xml as a child of `fragment_a.xml`'s already-existing `LinearLayout`?